# Azure Pipelines: Where is the output of my script?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I tried to build my Angular 13 app on a self-hosted agent and created the following YAML snippet for this:

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '14.x'
- script: |    
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --configuration production --aot
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src'
```

I can observe the /s directory of the agent _work-directory and after my task was running, there is no node_modules folder or dist folder inside.

But also no console output.

If I remove the line "npm install -g @angular/cli" from the line, a node_modules folder gets created, but no dist-folder.
I am pretty sure that the installation of angular cli fails, but I do not get any error output in my window.
It just looks like this:

[image]

How can I get more logs to find out why the angular cli is not installing correctly? I saw that the "script" file that is executed on the agent puts an @echo off by default in front of the script.
Why is that?
How can I get some output to find my problem?

Comment: Please post your solution if you found one. I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

To get more detailed log from the pipeline you can add the variable `system.debug` and set the value to `true` in your pipeline.

For YAML pipelines, you can select Variables in the upper right corner of the YAML edit page.

[image]

Add a new variable with the name System.Debug and value true.

[image]

For more info about logs, please refer to [Review logs to diagnose pipeline issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops).

Comment: I'm still not seeing logs